# Which is the better way to read/write txt file

Tags: c#, file

What I want to do is to read/write text file as follows:

1. Display the .txt file content in a control, such as RichTextBox
2. Save the text in RichTextBox to a specified .txt file

The txt file size won't be large. There are several methods that could do the job, but I am not sure which one is better

1. TextReader/TextWriter
2. File class, by using File.ReadAll, File.WriteAll

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using RichTextBox, the control itself support, reading and writing files. - 
[RichTextBox Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.aspx)

Comment: +1, you should mention the method though and that `RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText` should be specified if the user does want to maintain the actual .txt as indicated by the question

Comment: The APIs are RichTextBox.LoadFile / SaveFile

Answer (score 1):

[File.ReadAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368.aspx) and [File.WriteAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375.aspx) are a good choice for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by "better way". If you mean simplicity, of course ReadAllText and WriteAllText  are the answer. But if you mean performance, the answer is "there is no difference for this amount of data.".